# Can't read from the source file or disk - M.2 SSD no solution

Tags: ssd

I have an issue that's been driving me nuts - I have a 2TB Seagate HDD with some video files on it which I'm trying to move off - I've tried moving them off to an External HD, another internal M.2 etc.

Every time - the process starts, runs till about 50% then this error pops up:

> "Can't read from the source file or disk"

I've tried giving privileges to "Everyone" - I've tried `ChkDsk C: /f /r /x` - which ran overnight and repaired but did not fix the issue.

I downloaded the Kingston SSD Manager but it does not recognise the drives - with the following error:

> "Detected as Secondary Drive - KScode2 Identify failed."

I've searched high and low for a solution but no-one seems to have a working fix.

Is this HDD dying and if so, how can I preserve the material on it?

To be clear, I can fully access the drive and write to it just fine, everything on the drive works including running games and playing the videos  - the only thing I can't do is get large files off.

[image]

I also used FastCopy to move a single file and after 40gb it errored with the following -

ReadFile(Data error (cyclic redundancy check).23)

Comment: You do not state whether you see "files" on the drive (as indicated by "50%") or whether it doesn't even "mount" (as indicated by SSD Manager). Look up file recovery software it might be worth a try. When you have as much of the files as possible; try formatting, a quick-format first, if that works then try one that writes the entire disk - if that latter works, then use it - but with caution.

Comment: Can you add screenshot of a SMART tool like CrystalDiskInfo?

Comment: Added - I can't embed yet since I don't have 10 reputation but it's on the link. Thanks

Comment: The screenshot you show is of a Seagate HDD, not the SSD in question. You need to select the correct drive near the top of the window.

Comment: My apologies, I was looking at the wrong drive in HWINFO - It is infact a 2TB SATA HDD not an SSD. Post edited to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

The Kingston SSD Manager cannot identify the disk, CHKDSK did not fix the issue.

So yes, most likely the disk is dying.

Try something the Easus SSD Recovery tool.  Otherwise take the drive to a local recovery agency and see if they can recover the files.

I do not think you should get your hopes up.